# Is there row selection event in Primefaces editable datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to get `row selection event` from the `Primefaces` `Editable Datatable` when I click the `pencil icon` of row.
There are two event `rowEdit` and `rowEditCancel`.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" id="carList" editable="true">  
    ...
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}" update=":form:messages" />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tableBean.onCancel}" update=":form:messages" />  
    .....
</p:dataTable>
```

**rowEdit event :** This event is trigger when the user click `tick mark` icon.

Listener Method of rowEdit Event

```
public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {  
    ....
}
```

**rowEdit event :** This event is trigger when the user click `cross mark` icon.

Listener Method of rowEditCancel Event

```
public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {  
    ...
}
```

I would like to trigger when the user click `pencil mark` icon. Is there listener method for that?

Answer (score 6):

As read in the [Primefaces User Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2.pdf) (on page 154) there is a `rowEditInit` event.

> rowEditInit | When a row switches to edit mode

This one fires, when after the `pencil mark` icon has been clicked.

```xml
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{tableBean.onEditInit}"
        update=":form:messages" />
```

The according listener could look like this.

```java
public void onEditInit(RowEditEvent event) {
    System.out.println("onEditInit: " + event.getObject());
}
```